# Javascript: Increasing the price of a item

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to add a feature.
When the player buys this item, the player can buy it again but the price  increases a little each time.
So far I managed to do it successfully but I lost the code. :(
I can't remember what i did to the code though.
**The problem is that when the player buys the item the price does not change *unless you refresh the page*.** 
For example:
Player brought Item for 10
The new price becomes 20 but it still says 10.
i don't understand what's wrong.
Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<button onclick="HatchCounter();">Add item</button> You have <div id="hatch"></div> item Cost <span id="demo"></span> item
```

Javascript:

```
        
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    if (x > 10) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 10*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    var d = c
    }
    if (x > 20) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 11*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 30) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 12*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 40) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 13*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 60) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 14*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 70) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 15*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 90) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 16*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 100) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 17*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
    if (x > 110) {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 18*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    }
     else {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('Hatchcount')
    var y = ++x + 9*x
    var c = Math.ceil(y)
    var d = c
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "" + d + "";
    function HatchCal()
    {
        if (localStorage.clickcount > c ){
        hatchisvalid();
    } else { 
        notenough();
    }
    }
    function hatchisvalid() {
    HatchCounter(); HatchCou(); localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)-c;document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "" + d + "";
    }
    function HatchCounter() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.Hatchcount) {
                localStorage.Hatchcount = Number(localStorage.Hatchcount)+1;
            } else {
                localStorage.Hatchcount = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById("hatch").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.Hatchcount + ""; document.getElementById("hatchlvl").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.Hatchcount + "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hatch").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    }
    function HatchCal()
    {
        if (localStorage.clickcount > c ){
        HatchCounter(); HatchCou(); localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)-c;
    } else { 
        notenoughbob();
    }
    }
```

**Edit:** I've found out the problem. The script is loaded once the page loads, so demo only updates when the script loads. Is there a way to load the script every few seconds? Or load the script by a function? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Fix your HTML first! Full of syntax errors. Also, `BuyIteml` is not equal to `BuyItem1`

Comment: Shouldn't your onclick be `onclick="BuyItem()"`? As in, missing `()`

Comment: @RyanLittle You don't fix errors in edits!!!

Comment: Guys go light on the dislike. Not no way to welcome a new member.

Comment: @RyanLittle No, as in, if you fix the JS in your question edit, then the question is no longer needed. People post issues they have with code, you don't go about 'answering' the question by simply editing their question. Leave your 'fixes' in an answer. What you've done is NOT the point of question edits.

Comment: I was working on the answer for you. If you re-post the your code I can fix it for you. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to explain that it would be better to put the localStorage value and the current price grabbed from the DOM and put them into a variable. Also I was that you had a gang of if statements. It would be more efficient to use a switch statement. If you have more than two if statements then us a switch.      https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch04s02.html

Comment: Where is that first if statement supposed to close?

Comment: Thanks, At the last "Else" bit.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it seems to check it again at the bottom

Comment: It should close at  "if (localStorage.clickcount > c ){
        hatchisvalid();
    } else { 
        notenough();
    }
    }"
    function hatchisvalid()<---above this

Comment: Your if statements don't really seem logical... The last and only else statement is just `if (x > 110) { ... } else { ... }`. Does that make sense? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I mean is, that else does not work with all the other if statements together. Perhaps a switch statement may be more suitable.

Comment: I tried "else if" but the same problem occur. I'll try switch, thanks.

Comment: Do you want the logic to be like... say `x = 80`. Do you want both `if (x > 60) { ... }` and `if (x > 70) { ... }` to take place, or just `if (x > 70)`?

Comment: The logic that i actually want: X + 20% of X = New Price sent to demo, but any logic will do fine.. I'll go with "Both" (if (x > 60) { ... } and if (x > 70) { ... } to take place)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML fix the Raptor was talking about is a quick one. Just change this:

```
<button onclick="BuyItem">Buy</button> Cost: <span id="demo"></demo>
```

to this:

```
<button onclick="BuyItem">Buy</button> Cost: <span id="demo"></span>
```

it was the closing span tag at the end.

First thing is that you want to cache your DOM and localStorage values and elements. Both of those are expensive hits on performance.

You have to many quotes around your innerHTML assignment.

```
document.getElementById("hatch").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.Hatchcount + "";
```

You needs to do a quote on both sides of the value asignment.

```
document.getElementById("hatch").innerHTML = " + localStorage.Hatchcount + ";
```

P.S. I would still cache the DOM and localStorage stuff then evaluate against that.

Comment: It seemed like there were more errors in the JS though, we'll see when OP re-posts the code

Comment: Done. I've posted the full code. The errors on the html does not matter much, it's mainly in the JavaScript.